# Pygame Accessing variables in functions

Tags: python, function, pygame

Hey I've been trying to call the pygame events in a function to reduce the clutter of my code. But I am unable to perform the process due to an error with global variables. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame, sys
def color():
    screen.fill((85,163,48)) 

def events():
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
        print "left"
#sets the game map variables
tilesize = 100
map_width = 600
map_height = 300
#initialises the game screen setting it up with the game map variables
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((map_width,map_height))

while True:
    color()
    events()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Well the code is improperly indented, so that would be the first thing to fix. Beyond that, can you give us your specific error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unable to access a value locally from within a function, the answer is to simply pass the value into the function. Something simple like this should suffice:

```
def events(ev_list):
    for event in ev_list:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

within your game loop you'd call it with:

```
event_list = pygame.event.get()
events(event_list)
```

alternatively (less desirable) you can import a library from within the function or declare a variable global